# iOS 32-bit support gone in latest upload

Tags: ios, 32-bit, xcode9.1

Since my latest update in the App Store, customers with older iPads are complaining that the app doesn't support their devices anymore.
Deployment target is set to iOS 9, so that part should be OK.
When building and running on my iPad mini 1 from xcode it works fine, but when looking it up in the App Store, iPad mini 1 isn't supported by the app.

Did I accidentally change a setting, or is it the way it is from now on?

(XCODE 9.1)

Comment: What’s in your “Architectures” setting?

Comment: Architectures: $(ARCHS-STANDARD)

Comment: Valid Architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the info.plist file the "Required device capabilities" should include "armv7". That fixed it.